# Type Rank IN Ndepend

Tags: ndepend

1)In our application  we have found two different  ranks  one is  287 and another one is 409.
   Which one is best  rank .what are the  code changes developer has to do to get better rank to all the methods.

2)with the help of rank how can we say our method is successfully passed by  all Rules of NDepend .

Answer (score 0):

Type Rank or Method rank, higher or lower value, is not better or worse.

It just indicates popularity of a type, if it is used a lot or not. Internally the famous [Page Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm is used on the graph of types and the graph of methods.

Type rank documentation is [here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#TypeRank).

*Recommendations: Types with high TypeRank should be more carefully tested because bugs in such types will likely be more catastrophic.*